# How to convert mp3 data to wav data?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, mp3, wav, pydub

I have a wav audio file and i extracted data from that wav using python pydub module and i got this data

[-139   18 -215   34 -196    6 -295  -31 -301  -35 -211   13  -93   47
-60   39  -58    7  -17    2]

(this is first 10 data i got more than 1 million data)

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
import numpy as np

song = AudioSegment.from_file("test.wav")
extract_data = np.array(song.get_array_of_samples())
print(extract_data[:10])
```

then i converted wav to mp3 using that module and again extracted data from mp3 file and  i got this data

[-108    7 -193   24 -223   11 -239  -31 -248  -43 -203  -10 -101   23
-14   24   10   15   24   16]

(this is first 10 data i got more than 1 million data)

```
song = AudioSegment.from_file("test.wav")
song.export("test.mp3")
mp3_song = AudioSegment.from_file("test.mp3")
extract_data = np.array(mp3_song.get_array_of_samples())
print(extract_data[:10])
```

and again i converted mp3 to wav now i got mp3 data instead of wav data.

```
mp3_song = AudioSegment.from_file("test.mp3")
mp3_song.export("test1.wav", format="wav")

song = AudioSegment.from_file("test1.wav")
extract_data = np.array(song.get_array_of_samples())
print(extract_data[:10])
```

My point is how to convert mp3 data to original wav data?

please help me,

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Because .MP3 uses 'lossy' compression, you wont get the same data back when converted as data is 'lossed'. *The data is compressed and information is lost in the process.*

If you were to convert back and forth indefinetely the data would degrade indefinetely!

Impossible to get the data back!

Comment: The OP should clarify, do they mean that they want the compressed mp3 -> to a .wav?

Comment: I want my uncompressed .wav data back from .mp3 file.

Comment: Not possible.  You can make it uncompressed wav again, as you did.  It may not have much loss, even.  But once compressed, there's no going back.